# finding a string inside a string using wildcards (Powershell)

Tags: powershell

I have a long string: 
lqmdkqsdkdqBEGIN{dsqldqsazadksqld},dqsdlqsm},dlqsmd

I want to substract  BEGIN{dsqldqsazadksqld} from it using wildcards BEGIN{*} , but not B̶E̶G̶I̶N̶{̶d̶s̶q̶l̶d̶q̶s̶a̶z̶a̶d̶k̶s̶q̶l̶d̶}̶,̶d̶q̶s̶d̶l̶q̶s̶m̶}̶

how do i achieve this with **Powershell** ?

Comment: this seems to work >>> `-match '^.+(begin{.+}).+$'` <<< the captured group will be in `$Matches[1]`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey `+` is greedy by default `.+` will match the first closing `}` as well

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - arg! [*blush*] thank you for that reminder. you are quite correct that lazy matching would be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex instead of wildcard matching:

```
PS ~> 'lqmdkqsdkdqBEGIN{dsqldqsazadksqld},dqsdlqsm},dlqsmd' -replace '^.*(BEGIN\{[^}]+\}).*$','$1'
BEGIN{dsqldqsazadksqld}
```

The regular expression pattern `^.*(BEGIN\{[^}]+\}).*$` describes:

```
^          # start of string
 .*        # 0 or more of any characters
 (         # start capture group 1
  BEGIN\{  # match literal string `BEGIN{`
  [^}]+    # 1 or more non-`}` characters
  \}       # a literal `}`
 )         # end capture group
 .*        # 0 or more of any characters
$          # end of string
```

The `$1` in the substitution string is replaced with the value captured by the group described in the pattern.

Comment: @Kratozz Great, you're welcome! Consider marking my answer "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left :-)